# How to set custom referer header for a http requests to get external css

Tags: php, html, css

I'm coding a page and I need to know how to set a custom referer in the header of a http requests that my server will do to get external CSS from another website.

For example: when I try to get external CSS from a particular website ([www.x.com/style.css](http://www.x.com/style.css)) using normal headers ( where referer is anything ). I get (403 forbidden) as response code and my server fails to get that CSS

but when I try to get the same external CSS from ([www.x.com/style.css](http://www.x.com/style.css)) using referer with value http://www.x.com ( the same website where the CSS file is located ) I get the style,

by the way, it is not possible to download that CSS and put it directly because the CSS itself contains some external fonts and images that only can be found at ([www.x.com](http://www.x.com)) and I can't rebuild it from scratch

I hope you understand my question

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are legally allowed to do as you suggest, but alas, this is not a legal advice platform. If you get in trouble for doing that, you are on your own.

I cannot emphasize it enough: even if you are able to copy it, it does not mean you have the right to do it. If you are not supposed to do it, you are violating copyrights.

What you have to do is to set up a proxy, say “www.xproxy.my domain.com” that receives the request for the css, makes itself the same request to the original, adding the header, and then changes the response so all references to “www.x.com” are changed to point to your proxy too.

If you are lucky, the CSS has only relative paths, so you only have to just proxy everything and change nothing.

Then you point your page to your proxy, and boom! you have all your nice stolen CSS and images and fonts. Congrats!!!